# Why is X library reporting wrong string length values?

Tags: haskell, x11, xlib, xorg

I was trying to get the width of the string, using `XTextWidth()` function, but for some reason the returned value is always bigger than the actual displayed length of string. In the following example, the value printed out is `196`, while if I measure the width on-screen, it's somewhere around `168` pixels (the following is compilable and runnable example):

```
import Control.Concurrent
import qualified Graphics.X11.Xlib as X
import qualified Graphics.X11.Xlib.Types as Xt
import qualified Graphics.X11.Types as Xt

main = do
  display <- X.openDisplay ""
  let dflt = X.defaultScreen display
      border = X.blackPixel display dflt
      background = X.whitePixel display dflt
  rootw <- X.rootWindow display dflt
  win <- X.createSimpleWindow display rootw 0 0 500 300 1 border background
  X.mapWindow display win
  X.moveWindow display win 0 0

  updateScreen display win

updateScreen display win = do
  gc <- X.createGC display win
  bgcolor <- initColor display "white"
  fgcolor <- initColor display "black"
  X.setBackground display gc bgcolor
  X.setForeground display gc fgcolor

  font <- X.loadQueryFont display "-misc-fixed-*-*-*-*-14-*-*-*-*-*-*"
  let str = "Some reasonably long string."
      len = X.textWidth font str
  putStrLn $ show len
  X.drawImageString display win gc 0 50 str

  X.freeFont display font
  X.freeGC display gc
  threadDelay 100000
  updateScreen display win

initColor :: X.Display -> String -> IO X.Pixel
initColor dpy color = do
  let colormap = X.defaultColormap dpy (X.defaultScreen dpy)
  (apros,_) <- X.allocNamedColor dpy colormap color
  return $ X.color_pixel apros
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not displaying with the selected font. Try this:

```
X.setFont display gc $ X.fontFromFontStruct font
```